# Give space to array of signs in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

considering each sign always in the start or end of the string only, we want to give each sgin a space before or after so as a word:

The desired result is commented, My function has an issue as you see:

```js
modify('you always have to wake up?'); // you always have to wake up ? 

modify('...you always have to wake up'); // ... you always have to wake up

modify('...you always have to wake up?!'); // ... you always have to wake up ?!

function modify(string) {
    const sgins = ['?', '!', '...', '?!', '!?', '!!', '.'];
  for (let a = 0; a < sgins.length; a++) {
    const split = string.split(sgins[a]);
    string = string.replaceAll(sgins[a], ` ${sgins[a]} `).trim();
  }
  console.log(string);
}
```

How would you do this?

Comment: It's a specific  data processing need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple regex:

```
string.replace(/$[?!.]+/, '$& ');
```

Means replace all continuous `?!.` characters with the characters plus a space in the beginning of the string. The same for the end.

```js
modify('you always have to wake up?'); // you always have to wake up ? 

modify('...you always have to wake up'); // ... you always have to wake up

modify('...you always have to wake up?!'); // ... you always have to wake up ?!

function modify(string) {
   string = string.replace(/^[?!.]+/, '$& ').replace(/[?!.]+$/, ' $&');
   console.log(string);
}
```

If you need exact prefixes you can build the regexp:

```js
modify('you always have to wake up?'); // you always have to wake up ? 

modify('...you always have to wake up'); // ... you always have to wake up

modify('...you always have to wake up?!'); // ... you always have to wake up ?!

function modify(string) {

  const sgins = ['?', '!', '...', '?!', '!?', '!!', '.'];

  const options = sgins.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length).map(prefix => [...prefix].map(c => '\\' + c).join('')).join('|');

  string = string.replace(new RegExp('^(' + options + ')'), '$1 ').replace(new RegExp('(' + options + ')$'), ' $1');
  
  console.log(string);
}
```

Comment: @RaolmAX thanks, didn't notice the ends :)

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev You have error in second snippet my friend.


{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: sgins.toSorted is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 34
}""

Comment: @Piterek237 you can some old browser

Answer (score 1):

First off I would not use split() to be honest with You. I would write this like that, but this is **not optimal code**. This is not for all cases, I had to replace some signs of Your array to work. If You want to make it perfect, then you have to program this for a lot of different cases so code would be a little bigger. Cause for example what if there already is space? ETC.

```js
function modify(string) {
  let didEnd = false;
  let didStart = false;
    
  const sgins = ['?!', '!?', '!!', '!', '?', '...', '.'];
  for (let a = 0; a < sgins.length; a++) {
    if (string.startsWith(sgins[a]) && !didStart) {
      string = string.replace(sgins[a], `${sgins[a]} `);
      didStart = true;
    }
    if (string.endsWith(sgins[a]) && !didEnd) {
      string = string.replace(sgins[a], ` ${sgins[a]}`);
      didEnd = true;
    }
  }
  console.log(string);
}

modify('you always have to wake up?');
modify('...you always have to wake up'); 
modify('...you always have to wake up?!');
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use a pattern with a global match `/g` with 2 capture groups.

In the callback check for group 1 or group 2 to prepend or append a space.

```
const regex = /^([?!.]+)|([?!.]+)$/g;
```

```js
modify('you always have to wake up?'); // you always have to wake up ? 
modify('...you always have to wake up'); // ... you always have to wake up
modify('...you always have to wake up?!'); // ... you always have to wake up ?!

function modify(string) {
  const regex = /^([?!.]+)|([?!.]+)$/g;
  console.log(string.replace(regex, (_, g1, g2) => g1 ? g1 + " " : " " + g2));
}
```